# Conditional pasting of values from different columns in R (ignoring NAs)

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-formatting, dplyr

I have a dataset of patients with certain disorders (`Diag_main`). Some of these disorders have subcategorical diagnosis (`Diag_subgroup_CBS` or `Diag_subgroup_PPA`). For example, individuals with values =CBS in `Diag_main` will have corresponding Type 1 or Type 2 values (in `Diag_subgroup_CBS`) and individuals with values=PPA in `Diag_main` will have PPA-A or PPA-B.

Example data:

```r
df<-data.frame(
  id=c(1:7), 
  Diag_main=c('BBA', 'CBS', 'PPA', 'AM', 'CBS', 'PPA', 'BBA'), 
  Diag_subgroup_CBS=c(NA, '0', NA, NA, '1', NA, NA), 
  Diag_subgroup_PPA=c(NA, NA, '0', NA, NA, NA, '1')
)
```

**What I'm looking for:**

I want to create a new column (`Diag_combined`) that (i) for CBS: recodes 0 as Type1 and 1 as Type2, (ii) for PPA: recodes 0 as PPA-A and 1 as PPA-B, (iii) for individuals with CBS or PPA, pastes their Subgroup value, (i.e., Type1, PPA-A etc.) and (ii) for individuals without CBS or PPA, pastes their `Diag_main` value.

```r
df2<-data.frame(
  id=c(1:7), 
  Diag_main=c('BBA', 'CBS', 'PPA', 'AM', 'CBS', 'PPA', 'BBA'), 
  Diag_subgroup_CBS=c(NA, '0', NA, NA, '1', NA, NA), 
  Diag_subgroup_PPA=c(NA, NA, '0', NA, NA, NA, '1'), 
  Diag_combined=c('BBA', 'Type1', 'PPA-A', 'AM', 'Type2', 'PPA-B', 'BBA')
)
```

I tried doing this using `dplyr::mutate` using this code:

```r
df3 <- mutate(df,
  Diag_combined=ifelse(grepl('0', Diag_subgroup_CBS), 'Type1', 
                       ifelse(grepl('1', Diag_subgroup_CBS), 'Type2',  
                              ifelse(grepl('0', Diag_subgroup_PPA), 'PPA-A', 
                                     ifelse(grepl('1', Diag_subgroup_PPA), 'PPA-B', Diag_main))))))
```

When I run this, I get errors stating `Problem with 'mutate()' column 'Diag_combined'. The error occurred in Diag_combined: id = 1.`. I don't know if this is because `dplyr::mutate` is not ignoring NAs.

I don't understand why this code is not working. What's the fastest and most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write conditions in `case_when()` combined with `mutate()`

```
df %>%
mutate(Diag_combined = case_when(Diag_main == 'BBA' ~ 'BBA',
                                Diag_main == 'CBS' & Diag_subgroup_CBS == 0 ~ 'Type1',
                                Diag_main == 'PPA' & Diag_subgroup_PPA == 0 ~ 'PPA-A',
                                Diag_main == 'AM' ~ 'AM',
                                Diag_main == 'CBS' & Diag_subgroup_CBS == 1 ~ 'Type2',
                                Diag_main == 'PPA' & is.na(Diag_subgroup_CBS) & is.na(Diag_subgroup_PPA) ~ 'PPA-B') %>% as.factor)
```

output;

```
id Diag_main Diag_subgroup_CBS Diag_subgroup_PPA Diag_combined
  <int> <fct>     <fct>             <fct>             <fct>        
1     1 BBA       NA                NA                BBA          
2     2 CBS       0                 NA                Type1        
3     3 PPA       NA                0                 PPA-A        
4     4 AM        NA                NA                AM           
5     5 CBS       1                 NA                Type2        
6     6 PPA       NA                NA                PPA-B        
7     7 BBA       NA                1                 BBA
```